# Accessing an empty attribute in less

Tags: javascript, css, attributes, less, selector

I am using a less file to style my html elements and I am trying to access the input element with the attribute 'kendo-date-time-picker'.

The html is as follows:

```
<input kendo-date-time-picker
               ng-switch-when="dateTimePicker"
               k-ng-model="$parent.model"
               k-format="'HH:mm - dd.MM.yy'"
               k-time-Format="'HH:mm'"
               data-on-change="change()"
               data-ng-readonly="readonly"
               data-ng-disabled="disabled"
               data-ng-required="required"
               data-ng-focus="focus($event)"
               data-ng-blur="blur()"
               interval="15"
               />
```

And my less file looks like this at the moment:

```
& input[kendo-date-time-picker]{
    span{
        .slave{
            background: rgb(233, 231, 231) !important;
        }

        .k-picker-wrap.k-state-disabled{
            background-image: none !important;
            height: 30.3px;
            opacity: 1 !important;
            background: rgb(233, 231, 231) !important;
            border-width: 0px !important;
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know, this should access any input elements with the attribute: 'kendo-date-time-picker', but it doesn't work.

Forget about the '&'- selector, this is nested in a different element.
What am I doing wrong? Can somebody help me with this?

Greetings

Comment: It doesn't work because you seem to be nesting a `span` inside an `input` which is not valid HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! But how can I access the span and the elements on the span (coming with the kendo date time picker) via the input element?

Comment: I haven't used Kendo and so don't know how the structure would look like but have a look at James' answer and I think that should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, that really helped solving this

Answer (score 2):

`span` elements are not allowed to be contained within `input` elements. Your browser is probably *fixing* this for you by moving the `span` element outside, so your markup will end up looking similar to:

```
<input ... />
<span> ... </span>
```

If you wish to select the `span` element directly after your `[kendo-date-time-picker]` element, you can use the [Adjacent Sibling Combinator (`+`) selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators):

```css
input[kendo-date-time-picker] + span {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The situation as it is, is that the span is surounding the input element. Can I access the surouinding input element in any way via less?

Thanks for your fast answer James!

Comment: @DisconnectYourNeighbours as far as I'm aware you cannot select the parent element, even with LESS. What is `.slave` supposed to be?

Comment: .slave selects the span with the class="slave". It actually looks like this:

 <span class="slave" ng-switch="inputType">
            <input kendo-date-time-picker />
 </span>

I solved the issue by selecting the surrounding class and then going down onto the span.

Comment: @DisconnectYourNeighbours your current LESS example attempts to select an element with class `.slave` within your `span` element. You should use `&.slave` if you want to select that specific `span`.

Comment: @DisconnectYourNeighbours You should definitely put your HTML into your question.